# Wait for one plt figure to be closed by user before opening the next in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am iterating through a for loop as shown in the code below.

```
for i in range(0, mvmt_array.shape[0], BINS_IN_HOUR):
    mvmt_day = mvmt_array[i:i+BINS_IN_HOUR]
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.heatmap(mvmt_day.T)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
    'button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event, ax))
    
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
    plt.show()
```

As you can see - I have the figures set up to be interactive so that the user can click on coordinates, get results etc.

For every for loop iteration, as soon as the user clicks once it opens the next figure. I don't want that.

I want the next figure to pop-up only if the user closes the current one and is done interacting with it.

How can I do this? I tried using `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` but this still gives me the same problem i.e. as soon as a click is pressed once it opens the next figure

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out - must use:

`plt.show(block=True)` to allow for infinite amounts of interaction before moving onto next figure!

Comment: You could also maybe put them in different functions calling the appropriate function when necessary